# Influence of correlation of 2 or more normally distributed variables.

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation

Beginner question I think :

I have 2 variables A and B ( both normally distributed)

```
A( mean=1 stdv 5)
B( mean 10, stdv 20)

there correlation value is +0.3
```

If know A has increased by 10% to mean 1.1,

can I give a new distribution for B and how does that look like in numbers ?

Comment: In your title you say "normally distributed", but there's no mention of "normal" in the post itself ... if that's your intention, it's worth adding to the post. Do you know the formula for the \density function of a two-variable normal distribution?

Comment: I added it ( thank you), yes I know that function, but unfortunately I do not understand how it relates to my question. Please give me a hint :)